# Published Sony Smartwatch 2 App not recognized

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch, google-play

I published an App in Google Play Store and also added: Smart Connect extension for SmartWatch 2 to the description (seperately in every translation of the description) but unfortunately my App is not showing when I do a search in the Play Store for Smart Extension or from the Smartwatch2 App.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How long did you give it?

Comment: It's almost one week online

Answer (score 0):

The string appears to be correct.  Unfortunately we don't have any control of publishing and it sounds like a Google Play issue so you will need to contact them.

Comment: I did but they say that it's not easy to refine the search results appropriately when it comes to generic words that also happen to be brand names or titles and that they hope to address my concern in the future. What I don't understand is why it's not working for my app if the string is right.

Comment: So just to be clear, is the issue that your app is published to the store but not showing up when you search for "Smart Connect extension for SmartWatch 2"?  For example if you input your package name in the following URL does it show your app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=(replace with your package name)

If the issue is with the search results from "Smart Connect extension for SmartWatch 2" there is a limitation on the number of results that show (250 max) so apps after that won't be found.  Unfortunately this is a store limit and right now we don't know of any workaround.

Comment: I realized that the search results are limited. I still don't know with which criteria google is showing the results because it is not random it is always showing the same apps. Thank you for your answer.